# Form object not iterable in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I want to assign the input of a form to a function in my view but I keep getting this error. Please help do I fix it.

**Error**

```
receiver = list(ToolsForm.declared_fields['receiver_mail'])
TypeError: 'CharField' object is not iterable
```

Comment: That should be `receiver = ToolsForm.cleaned_data['receiver_mail']` so *without* the `list(...)` part and with `.cleaned_data`.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the value associated with the `receiver_mail` field with:

```
receiver = form.cleaned_data['receiver_mail']
```

so *without* using `list(…)` part and with [**`.cleaned_data`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data), the form should be an *instance* of `ToolForm`, not a reference to the `ToolForm` class. Before you can retrieve the data, you will first need to validate the form, so:

```
form = ToolsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    receiver = form.cleaned_data['receiver_mail']
```